# Getting admob above actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, admob, actionbarsherlock

I want to use AdMob and ActionBarSherlock in the same android aplication, but I don't manageto put AdMob on the top of my screen (above Sherlock ActionBar).

Anyone had some similar problems? Does anyone knows about some workaround?

Thanks.

My general layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" > 
<include layout="@layout/admob"/> 
<TabHost
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout.....
```

My admob layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.ads.AdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ads:adUnitId="123456"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using ActionBarSherlock as wrapper and the following puts the ad above the action bar:

```
private ActionBarSherlock sherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    /* ... set up layout here ... */


    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "deadbeefmeat");

    ViewParent parentView = appView.getParent();
    do
    {
        parentView = parentView.getParent();
    } while(!(parentView instanceof LinearLayout));

    ((LinearLayout)parentView).addView(adView, 0);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

// All setContentView methods are overridden because ActionBarSherlock has to modify the view
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID)
{
    // Don't call super!
    sherlock.setContentView(layoutResID);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view)
{
    // Don't call super!
    sherlock.setContentView(view);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view, LayoutParams params)
{
    // Don't call super!
    sherlock.setContentView(view, params);
}
```

Comment: I haven't found a way how it works with build in Android ActionBar. Do you know a way? This is may question with android ActionBar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258323/how-to-place-admob-at-the-top-of-the-screen-above-android-actionbar